# Prove for $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x,y,z$ ( $0 \leq x < y < z$ ) such that $ n = \binom{x}{1} + \binom{y}{2} + \binom{z}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to solve a problem from the combinatorics book. Prove or disprove for $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x,y,z \in \mathbb{N} $ ($0 \leq x < y < z$) such that $$ n = \binom{x}{1} + \binom{y}{2} + \binom{z}{3}$$

I was trying to substitute binomial coefficients with:

$$ n = \binom{x}{1} + \binom{y}{2} + \binom{z}{3} = x + \frac{y*(y-1)}{2} + \frac{z*(z-1)*(z-2)}{3}$$

However, I've stucked after that. I know that any binomial coefficient is integer-valued. So, it's likely equation hold.

Comment: Great thanks! Should I remove my questions?

Comment: Is that book so popular or is it a coincidental duplicate question?

Comment: I guess the book is popular. It's free and decent. In Russian, thought. http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/pdf/alfutova.pdf

Comment: Ah I see!$   \ \ \ $